# .net angularjs application error on publish to server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, setup-deployment

I have an application in .NET MVC5 with angularJS. I started building it locally. When I publish it, I get the angular template error- **the template must have exactly one root element**. I checked the templates which are razor files. I tried flipping **replace to false** but that gives me a **service unavailable error page in the place of each template**. Has anybody faced this before? Any pointers on where I should start looking? If it is the project setup problem, what are the ways to resolve this?

P.S. I am a beginner in .NET.

Comment: The error that you get is on the console? can you show us some code?

Comment: Yes it is on the console. None of my custom directives' templates are loaded. I am not sure what code I should be showing here. I created a few directives with templateUrl as a function that returns the Url based on an attribute of the directive. The path seems correct, so I don't see any problem there.

Comment: Ok, yes, you must have a lot of code, well, maybe you have an errror in the each views and the layout, maybe you have any html tag duplicate, are you using layout? can put the layout (if you have) and the view?

Comment: Thank you @JulitoAvellaneda! The issue was with the property of the template files. They must have had a "Build Action" set to "Content". I had a view controller which returned error page's url on missing files. So when the files were initially not in the published folder organization, it redirected to the default error page which did not have one root element. Thus the error.